# Saving a Spark-SQL file as csv

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save the output of SparkSQL to a path but not sure what function to use. I want to do this without using spark data frames. I was trying using **write.mode("overwrite").csv("file:///home/user204943816622/Task_3a-out")** but not successful. Can someone tell how to do it?

Note: spark SQL will give the output in multiple files. Need to ensure that the data is sorted globally across all the files (parts). So, all words in part 0, will be alphabetically before the words in part 1.

```
case class Docword(docId: Int, vocabId: Int, count: Int)
case class VocabWord(vocabId: Int, word: String)

// Read the input data
val docwords = spark.read.
  schema(Encoders.product[Docword].schema).
  option("delimiter", " ").
  csv("hdfs:///user/bdc_data/t3/docword.txt").
  as[Docword]
val vocab = spark.read.
  schema(Encoders.product[VocabWord].schema).
  option("delimiter", " ").
  csv("hdfs:///user/bdc_data/t3/vocab.txt").
  as[VocabWord]

docwords.createOrReplaceTempView("docwords")
vocab.createOrReplaceTempView("vocab")

spark.sql("""SELECT vocab.word AS word1, SUM(count) count1 FROM
docwords INNER JOIN vocab
ON docwords.vocabId = vocab.vocabId
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY count1 DESC""").show(10)

write.mode("overwrite").csv("file:///home/user204943816622/Task_3a-out")

// Required to exit the spark-shell
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: what value you are assigning to write ?

Comment: Values derived in spark.sql("""SELECT vocab.word AS word1, SUM(count) count1 FROM
docwords INNER JOIN vocab
ON docwords.vocabId = vocab.vocabId
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY count1 DESC""").show(10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.show()` returns `void` you should dp something like below

```
val writeDf = spark.sql("""SELECT vocab.word AS word1, SUM(count) count1 FROM
docwords INNER JOIN vocab
ON docwords.vocabId = vocab.vocabId
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY count1 DESC""")
writeDf.write.mode("overwrite").csv("file:///home/user204943816622/Task_3a-out")
writeDf.show() // this should not be used in prod environment
```

Comment: What if I want to use Data frames to save the file and still use .show()?

Comment: it shows an error: write.mode("overwrite").csv("file:///home/user204943816622/Task_3a-out")
<console>:41: error: value mode is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
       write.mode("overwrite").csv("file:///home/user204943816622/Task_3a-out")

Comment: update the code for write naming convention with write method

Comment: can you tell how to do that?

Comment: I used it but it shows an error that is:     
writeDf.write().mode("overwrite").csv("file:///home/user204943816622/Task_3a-out")
<console>:137: error: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] does not take parameters
       writeDf.write().mode("overwrite").csv("file:///home/user204943816622/Task_3a-out")

Comment: can you change `writeDf.write().mode` to `writeDf.write.mode` and retry. I have updated the ans as well

Comment: Still getting error: 
 writeDf.write.mode("overwrite").csv("file:///home/user204943816622/Task_3a-out")
<console>:41: error: value write is not a member of Unit
       writeDf.write.mode("overwrite").csv("file:///home/user204943816622/Task_3a-out")
               ^

Comment: you did not remove .show() from .sql function ? @ManinderPreetSinghPuri

Comment: It works if I don't use .show(). Also it works with .take(). But I am trying to use .show() to print output.

Comment: please print after you have written the output as I suggested in my ans

Comment: accepted but can't upvote publicly as new to the platform.